# selenum parameterization error handling

Tags: javascript

I have written script for parameterization for login in selenium web driver for valid and invalid entries. script is running fine for valid inputs but stuck for invalid inputs now i want to handle that error for invalid entries and want to resume my script for next input. so how can i do it. please help me.

check for below code

```
public class Sample {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, BiffException, IOException {

    //Login Page
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

     driver.manage().window().maximize();
     //Login parameterization using excel sheet (Jxl.jar)
     Workbook wBook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("F:\\Selenium\\Parameterize\\login.xls"));
     int i = 1;
     //Get sheet
     Sheet sheet = wBook.getSheet(0);

     for(i = 1; i<sheet.getRows(); i++){
     driver.get("https://www.Google.com");

    //user name
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='j_username']")).sendKeys(sheet.getCell(0, i).getContents());
     //password
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='j_password']")).sendKeys(sheet.getCell(1, i).getContents());
     //submit
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='signInForm']/div/div/div[7]/div[2]/button")).click();
     Thread.sleep(5);

      //TO move mouse to display Sign Out drop down window
     Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
     WebElement getElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='welcomeSpanUserName']"));
     builder.moveToElement(getElement).build().perform();
     Thread.sleep(5);

    //Click on Sign Out button
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='wrapper']/div[2]/ul[2]/li[2]/ul/li[2]/span/a")).click();
     }
  }

}
```

Comment: Explore exception handling in java and use it..:)

Answer (score 1):

Try using try..catch block within the loop and if there is an exception it will proceed with next iteration.

```
public class Sample {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, BiffException, IOException {

    //Login Page
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

     driver.manage().window().maximize();
     //Login parameterization using excel sheet (Jxl.jar)
     Workbook wBook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("F:\\Selenium\\Parameterize\\login.xls"));
     int i = 1;
     //Get sheet
     Sheet sheet = wBook.getSheet(0);

  for(i = 1; i<sheet.getRows(); i++){

     try{
     driver.get("https://115.112.36.94:7443/");

    //user name
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='j_username']")).sendKeys(sheet.getCell(0, i).getContents());
     //password
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='j_password']")).sendKeys(sheet.getCell(1, i).getContents());
     //submit
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='signInForm']/div/div/div[7]/div[2]/button")).click();
     Thread.sleep(5);

      //TO move mouse to display Sign Out drop down window
     Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
     WebElement getElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='welcomeSpanUserName']"));
     builder.moveToElement(getElement).build().perform();
     Thread.sleep(5);

    //Click on Sign Out button
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='wrapper']/div[2]/ul[2]/li[2]/ul/li[2]/span/a")).click();
     }catch(Exception e){
       //handle exception if you need
     }
    }
  }

}
```